# Taking the difference of index families of classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the conclusion of a proof I am working on. The problem is from Charles Pinter's 'A book on Set Theory'. The problem is as follows:

> Let $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ and $\{ B_j \}_{j \in J}$ be index families of classes. Prove that:
>   $$ 
> \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) - \left( \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j \right) = \bigcup_{i \in I} \left(\bigcap_{j \in J} \left[ A_i - B_j \right] \right) 
> $$

My proof goes as follows:

$$ \begin{align} x \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) - \left( \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j \right) & \iff x \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \cap {\left( \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j \right)}^\complement \tag{1}
\\& \iff  x \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \cap \left( \bigcap_{j \in J} {B_j}^\complement \right) \tag{2}
\\ & \iff x \in A_i, \exists i \in I, \land x \in {B_j}^\complement , \forall j \in J \tag{3}
\\ & \iff x \in A_i \cap {B_j}^\complement , \exists i \in I, \forall j \in J \tag{4}
\\&  \iff x \in A_i - B_j , \exists i \in I, \forall j \in J \tag{5}
\\& \iff x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} \left(\bigcap_{j \in J} \left[ A_i - B_j \right] \right) \tag{6} \end{align}$$
$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \Box $

But wouldn't it also be correct to conclude $x \in \bigcap_{j \in J} \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} \left[ A_i - B_j \right] \right)$ ? Doesn't the order of operation matter in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the order of operation does matter in this case.

> As 
>   $$x \in A_i - B_j , \exists i \in I, \forall j \in J$$  doesn't imply $$x \in \bigcap_{j \in J} \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} \left[ A_i - B_j \right] \right) $$

You can easily find a counterexample to show this.

---

What I think is giving you trouble is the order of quantifiers.

To show that the order of quantifier does matter, consider the following two statements:-

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} , \exists y \in \mathbb{R}, y^5=x\tag{1}$$

$$ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} , y^5=x\tag{2}$$

Let us consider the translations of both the sentences into words.

$(1)$ "For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $y^5=x$"

This statement is true, for no matter what $x$ is there exists a number $y=\sqrt[5]{x}$ for which $y^5=x$.

$(2)$ "There exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$,for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $y^5=x$"

Another of way of saying this would be that there exists a particular $y$ with the property that $y^5=x$ for every real number $x$.

Clearly, this statement is false.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks @Roby5 ! You helped me notice a potential sloppiness I was doing in the proof. (3) , (4) , and (5) should have the index class quantifiers before $ x \in ... $ . Another thing I think I was doing wrongly was treating commas like "ands" so it seemed valid that the ordering of what came before and after the comma did not matter. The example you gave was very helpful.